# Toolbar display of an id specific variable from sqlite database very slow

Tags: sqlite, background-thread

Im using an sqlite database with provider and databasehelper. In a specific activity and some fragments (ordere by a FragmentPagerAdapter), I am trying to retrieve the name of a specific id to put it in the toolbar. I do this by creating a global variable with input from onLoadFinished in the activity and also in the fragments. This process is however very slow. The name is not immediately displayed. I have to refresh fragments (several times before the name is displayed. How can I make this more quick so that the name is immediately displayed?

Comment: You mention fragments, activities, and threads, is this an Android development question? If so, I'd highly advise you add that tag so people with relevant knowledge will see it.

Comment: Also, post code!